# Photoshop - PNG sequence to gif with trasparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, export, png

I have a problem with exporting all png sequence (these are all with the transparency, also been exported to video with after effect, selected rgb+alpha), the issue is that the optimized format shows me a "too much red" respect of the original one, I already made sure that the option matt has been disabled, also gif with the checkbox enabled into it. So don't know if there is something wrong with some setting. Thank you in advice, I will give you the images for references:
[image: original]
[image: optimized]

Thank you in advice for any help.

Comment: Simply not within the capabilities of a gif file.

Comment: @Tetsujin the apng method seems interesting, thank you for the info, will try that.